# WPF Toolkit Stacked100BarSeries chart

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, toolkit

I would like to modify (style) a WPF Toolkit Stacked100BarSeries chart to look and function something like this:
[image: chart]

I searched a lot how I could achieve this but it seems too complicated. I guess I should do this from code behind as the number of the series in the chart could be a lot (and it should be dynamic).

It should be timeline based and grouped by the 4 kind with these 4 colors (grey could be transparent).

This is what I could come up with:
[image: wpf chart]

Obviously this is not what I need. It has random colors, all the series are listed on the right, and it is not time based.
The values here come from KeyValuePairs, the DependentValuePath is "Value" and IndependentValuePath is "Key". This is how I achieve that more series are on the same line (series with "Key" A are on the first, etc).

This is the experimental (ugly) code:

```
Stacked100BarSeries barSeries = new Stacked100BarSeries();
SeriesDefinition s1 = new SeriesDefinition();
SeriesDefinition s2 = new SeriesDefinition();
SeriesDefinition s3 = new SeriesDefinition();
SeriesDefinition s4 = new SeriesDefinition();
SeriesDefinition s5 = new SeriesDefinition();
SeriesDefinition s6 = new SeriesDefinition();
SeriesDefinition s7 = new SeriesDefinition();
SeriesDefinition s8 = new SeriesDefinition();
SeriesDefinition s9 = new SeriesDefinition();
SeriesDefinition s10 = new SeriesDefinition();
SeriesDefinition s11 = new SeriesDefinition();
SeriesDefinition s12 = new SeriesDefinition();
s1.DependentValuePath = "Value";
s1.IndependentValuePath = "Key";
s2.DependentValuePath = "Value";
s2.IndependentValuePath = "Key";
s3.DependentValuePath = "Value";
s3.IndependentValuePath = "Key";
s4.DependentValuePath = "Value";
s4.IndependentValuePath = "Key";
s5.DependentValuePath = "Value";
s5.IndependentValuePath = "Key";
s6.DependentValuePath = "Value";
s6.IndependentValuePath = "Key";
s7.DependentValuePath = "Value";
s7.IndependentValuePath = "Key";
s8.DependentValuePath = "Value";
s8.IndependentValuePath = "Key";
s9.DependentValuePath = "Value";
s9.IndependentValuePath = "Key";
s10.DependentValuePath = "Value";
s10.IndependentValuePath = "Key";
s11.DependentValuePath = "Value";
s11.IndependentValuePath = "Key";
s12.DependentValuePath = "Value";
s12.IndependentValuePath = "Key";

List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> l1 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> l2 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> l3 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> l4 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> l5 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> l6 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> l7 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> l8 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> l9 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> l10 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> l11 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> l12 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    l1.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("D", i ));
    l2.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("D", i ));
    l3.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("D", i));
    l4.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("D", i ));
    l5.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("C", i));
    l6.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("C", i));
    l7.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("B", i ));
    l8.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("B", i));
    l9.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("B", i));
    l10.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("B", i ));
    l11.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("A", i));
    l12.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("A", i));
}

s1.ItemsSource = l1;
s2.ItemsSource = l2;
s3.ItemsSource = l3;
s4.ItemsSource = l4;
s5.ItemsSource = l5;
s6.ItemsSource = l6;
s7.ItemsSource = l7;
s8.ItemsSource = l8;
s9.ItemsSource = l9;
s10.ItemsSource = l10;
s11.ItemsSource = l11;
s12.ItemsSource = l12;

barSeries.SeriesDefinitions.Add(s1);
barSeries.SeriesDefinitions.Add(s2);
barSeries.SeriesDefinitions.Add(s3);
barSeries.SeriesDefinitions.Add(s4);
barSeries.SeriesDefinitions.Add(s5);
barSeries.SeriesDefinitions.Add(s6);
barSeries.SeriesDefinitions.Add(s7);
barSeries.SeriesDefinitions.Add(s8);
barSeries.SeriesDefinitions.Add(s9);
barSeries.SeriesDefinitions.Add(s10);
barSeries.SeriesDefinitions.Add(s11);
barSeries.SeriesDefinitions.Add(s12);

chart.Series.Add(barSeries);
```

In the XAML file there is only a Chart tag called "chart".

Comment: You need a completely different chart that isn't related with the bar chart at all. But it's not that easy to write it completely yourself.

Comment: so you say it is not possible to modify this stacked bar series as I want? That's bad news :/ But it is almost what I need...

Comment: It wasn't 'almost' at all. You needed gaps between bars, also an axis with time instead of percents, bars with the same color, a custom legend. A lot of things have to be changed. It would be easier to draw these rectangles on your own canvas than trying to change the toolkit charts.